# Layout content in HTML files with JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am creating a Java Swing application that displays an HTML page through a JEditorPane object. When the html page is displayed the layout content is different from original layout. Moreover the quality of the images displayed is very poor, although the original images have a good resolution. Are ways to tackle this display issue?

Comment: JEditorPane only supports HTML3.2 so it may not look like you expect if the HTML is complicated. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org
) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Browser support in Java sucks. It seems like the JWebPane will never happen.

Have a look at other options than JEditorPane:

lobobrowser.org

djproject.sourceforge.net/ns

jdic.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you're HTML is in fact XHTML compliant then you can use the excellent [xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) component instead.